# Why does my image have a thick black line around?

Tags: python, pygame

In Pygame, I have wrote a Minesweeper clone. However, when I blit the final image stating **YOU LOSE** or **YOU WIN**, I get this result:

[image]

I'm sure you notice the thick black line surrounding the text. Here is the function in which the image is blitted onto the window:

```
def play():
    SIZE = (WIDTH, HEIGHT) = (16, 16)
    MINES = 40
    PIXELS_PER_CELL = 30
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH * PIXELS_PER_CELL,
                                      HEIGHT * PIXELS_PER_CELL))
    pygame.display.set_caption("PyMines")
    board = create_board(SIZE, MINES)
    board.draw(screen)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and board.is_playing and
                  not board.is_solved):
                board.mouse_handler(event, screen)

        message = None
        if not board.is_playing:
            board.show_mines(screen)
            message = pygame.image.load("images/lose.png").convert_alpha()
        elif board.is_solved:
            message = pygame.image.load("images/win.png").convert_alpha()

        if message:
            message = pygame.transform.scale(message, (screen.get_width(),
                                                       screen.get_height() //
                                                       5))
            screen.blit(message, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
```

As I am not sure which part of the code you should be looking at, [here](http://pastebin.com/CcFHixnL) is the full code.

Another reason why I think this behaviour is so bizarre, is that when I first created PyMines, the image blitted perfectly like so (as you can see, there is a very slight shadow to the text):

[image]

This however, is not a optimized version, as after each cycle, the whole board is redrawn (so it takes a very long time on a 16x16 board as shown in the first image, so I used a 9x9 - but the results are the same). Here is the `play()` function of the original version:

```
def play():
    SIZE = (WIDTH, HEIGHT) = (9, 9)
    MINES = 10
    PIXELS_PER_CELL = 30
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH * PIXELS_PER_CELL,
                                      HEIGHT * PIXELS_PER_CELL))
    pygame.display.set_caption("PyMines")
    board = create_board(SIZE, MINES)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and board.is_playing and
                  not board.is_solved):
                board.mouse_handler(event, screen)

        message = None
        if not board.is_playing:
            board.show_mines()
            message = pygame.image.load("lose.png").convert_alpha()
        elif board.is_solved:
            message = pygame.image.load("win.png").convert_alpha()

        board.draw(screen)
        if message:
            message = pygame.transform.scale(message, (screen.get_width(),
                                                       screen.get_height() //
                                                       5))
            screen.blit(message, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
```

I would attach a link to the full code, but pastebin is down, so [here](http://pastebin.com/heGz6bAv) is the full code for the original game without the strange black line.

**EDIT**: I have already tried dropping the `convert_alpha()` and adding `convert()` or even nothing at all.

`.convert()`:

[image]

**NOTHING**:

[image]

Why are all these black lines there, how do I get rid of them and which version (`convert`/`convert_alpha`/**NOTHING**) should I use (and *how* to decide which one to use).

Comment: The problem seems to be with the `pygame.image.load("images/lose.png").convert_alpha()`. [This](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.convert_alpha) says that the loaded image might get altered. You should try the `.convert()` method instead.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Already tried that, it creates a solid black background, and dropping the `convert()` completely creates a smudgy black line

Comment: Maybe black line is created during `transform.scale()`. Create images with expected size.

Comment: Can I see the image before `transform.scale()`? Perhaps the original image has a thin black outline around the text and that outline is expanded with scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text has a black shadow with an alpha channel. In your original version, you render the board, then render the text, and the shadow gets blended with the board.

In the revised version, you render the board, then repeatedly render the text over it. On the first pass, it renders correctly, with the shadow blending with the board. On the second pass, the shadow blends with the shadow you've already rendered, making a slightly darker shadow. On the next pass, the shadow gets slightly darker, and so on.

You can't use alpha blending without keeping tight control over what you're blending over. Each time you render the text, you'll need to render at least the section of the board behind the text, if not the full board.